# Bash : reading regex from file and subsitute them into sed inline as variable

Tags: bash, variables, sed, data-masking

I am stuck with how sed interacts with variables. I am reading a list of regex from a file then substitute it into SED to mask certain sensitive information within a log file. if I hard coded the regex, the SED work perfectly, however it behave differently when used with variable.

```
con-list.txt contain below:
(HTTP\/)(.{2})(.*?)(.{2})(group\.com)
(end\sretrieve\sfacility\s)(.{2})(.*?)(.{3})$
```

Not sure if the dollar sign for regex is interfering with the SED command.

```
input="/c/Users/con-list.txt"
inputfiles="/c/Users/test.log"
echo $inputfiles
while IFS= read -r var
do
  #echo "Searching $var"
  count1=`zgrep -E "$var" "$inputfiles" | wc -l`
  if [ ${count1} -ne 0 ] 
  then
    echo "total:${count1} ::: ${var}"
    sed -r -i "s|'[$]var'|'\1\2XXXX\4\5'|g" $inputfiles #this doesnt work
    sed -r -i "s/(HTTP\/)(.{2})(.*?)(.{2})(group\.com)/'\1\2XXXX\4\5'/g"     $inputfiles #This works
    egrep -in "${var}" $inputfiles
  fi
done < "$input"
```

I need the SED to accept the regex as variable read from the file. So I could automate masking for sensitive information within logs.

```
$ ./zgrep2.sh
/c/Users/test.log
total:4 ::: (HTTP\/)(.{2})(.*?)(.{2})(group\.comp\.com\@GROUP\.COM)
sed: -e expression #1, char 30: invalid reference \5 on `s' command's RHS
```

Comment: Is the input file compressed (in which case you should use `zgrep` everywhere) or not (in which case you should not use `zgrep`)?

Comment: Can you use `sed -r -i -f "${input}" ${inputfiles}` (after editing the command in the input file) ?

Answer (score 2):

Your idea was right, but you forgot to leave the regex in the `sed` command to be under double quotes for `$var` to be expanded.

Also you don't need to use `wc -l` to count the match of occurrences. The family of utilities under `grep` all implement a `-c` flag that returns a count of matches. That said, you don't even need to count the matches, but use the return code of the command (if the match was found or not) simply as

```
if zgrep -qE "$var" "$inputfiles" ; then
```

Assuming you might need the count for debug purposes, you can continue with your approach with modifications to your script done as below

Notice how the `var` is interpolated in the `sed` substitution, leaving it expanded under double-quotes and once expanded preserving the literal values using the single-quote.

```
while IFS= read -r var
do
  count1=$(zgrep -Ec "$var" "$inputfiles")
  if [ "${count1}" -ne 0 ] 
  then
    sed -r -i 's|'"$var"'|\1\2XXXX\4\5|g' "$inputfiles"
    sed -r -i "s/(HTTP\/)(.{2})(.*?)(.{2})(group\.com)/'\1\2XXXX\4\5'/g" "$inputfiles"
    egrep -in "${var}" "$inputfiles"
  fi
done < "$input"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
sed -r -i "s/$var"'/\1\2XXXX\4\5/g' $inputfiles
```

You also need to provide sample input (a useful bit of the log file) so that we can verify our solutions.

EDIT: a slight change to $var and I think this is what you want:

```
$ cat ~/tmp/j
Got creds for HTTP/PPCKSAPOD81.group.com
Got creds for HTTP/PPCKSAPOD21.group.com
Got creds for HTTP/PPCKSAPOD91.group.com
Got creds for HTTP/PPCKSWAOD81.group.com
Got creds for HTTP/PPCKSDBOD81.group.com
Got creds for HTTP/PPCKSKAOD81.group.com
$ echo $var
(HTTP\/)(.{2})(.*?)(.{2})(.group\.com)
$ sed -r "s/$var"'/\1\2XXXX\4\5/' ~/tmp/j 
Got creds for HTTP/PPXXXX81.group.com
Got creds for HTTP/PPXXXX21.group.com
Got creds for HTTP/PPXXXX91.group.com
Got creds for HTTP/PPXXXX81.group.com
Got creds for HTTP/PPXXXX81.group.com
Got creds for HTTP/PPXXXX81.group.com
```

Comment: Hi Wef, Thanks for helping out. it doesn't create error anymore but the file wasn't masked as well. I been trying many days, almost went nuts

Please find log below.

<code>
    Got creds for HTTP/PPCKSAPOD81.group.com
    Got creds for HTTP/PPCKSAPOD21.group.com
    Got creds for HTTP/PPCKSAPOD91.group.com
    Got creds for HTTP/PPCKSWAOD81.group.com
    Got creds for HTTP/PPCKSDBOD81.group.com
    Got creds for HTTP/PPCKSKAOD81.group.com</code>

Comment: <code> ... </code> doesn't work. Indent each line by 4 spaces instead in this wiki. But I'll take a look.